# How do you find the total numbers of times a word has been used?

Tags: microsoft-excel

For example, say I'm trying to total yes/no questions. I want to be able to go down a column and see how many times the answer was yes and how many times the answer was no. I'm also using a drop-down selection to try to make things easier. I've tried using the sumif formula, but I am having trouble assigning value to the text.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"yes")
=COUNTIF(A:A,"no")
```

[image]